# renew localhost certificate for https

Tags: vue.js, https, certificate, localhost, ssl-certificate

I have a problem with ssl on my localhost.

```
NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID
Subject: localhost

Issuer: Avast trusted CA

Expires on: 3 feb 2031

Current date: 5 feb 2021

PEM encoded chain:
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIDOjCCAiKgAwIBAgICXpIwDQYJKoZ...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIDozCCAougAwIBAgIJAIS0/GKxwwKFM...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

I ger this error from google chrome when I try to access to it using `https://localhost`.
I've seen that the certificate is expired and maybe I need to renew it, but how to proceed on my macOS 10.13.6?I need to be able to have an https connection to be able to testing and implement push notifications in my vue app and to run `npm run serve` command under https connection.

this is the `apachectl -V` result

```
host:~ dev$ httpd -V
Server version: Apache/2.4.33 (Unix)
Server built:   Jan 18 2020 09:52:26
Server's Module Magic Number: 20120211:76
Server loaded:  APR 1.5.2, APR-UTIL 1.5.4
Compiled using: APR 1.5.2, APR-UTIL 1.5.4
Architecture:   64-bit
Server MPM:     prefork
  threaded:     no
    forked:     yes (variable process count)
Server compiled with....
 -D APR_HAS_SENDFILE
 -D APR_HAS_MMAP
 -D APR_HAVE_IPV6 (IPv4-mapped addresses enabled)
 -D APR_USE_FLOCK_SERIALIZE
 -D APR_USE_PTHREAD_SERIALIZE
 -D SINGLE_LISTEN_UNSERIALIZED_ACCEPT
 -D APR_HAS_OTHER_CHILD
 -D AP_HAVE_RELIABLE_PIPED_LOGS
 -D DYNAMIC_MODULE_LIMIT=256
 -D HTTPD_ROOT="/usr"
 -D SUEXEC_BIN="/usr/bin/suexec"
 -D DEFAULT_PIDLOG="/private/var/run/httpd.pid"
 -D DEFAULT_SCOREBOARD="logs/apache_runtime_status"
 -D DEFAULT_ERRORLOG="logs/error_log"
 -D AP_TYPES_CONFIG_FILE="/private/etc/apache2/mime.types"
 -D SERVER_CONFIG_FILE="/private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf"
```

Any help please?

Comment: I don't know what you are using, but I got similar error using laravel-echo-server. The issue was that laravel-echo-server don't update certificate. So I had to use a deamon to keep it alive and I use a cron job to stop laravel-echo-server once a week. I don't know if it can apply to you.

Comment: I've solved the issue by creating a new certificate that have replaced the old one.  since I'm using openssl v1.1.1i I've opted for this command `openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -sha256 -days 3650 -nodes   -keyout server.key -out server.crt -subj "/CN=localhost"   -addext "subjectAltName=DNS:localhost,IP:127.0.0.1"`